# Error while running TestNG tests using Maven

Tags: selenium

I am observing the following error: Cannot find class in classpath:name of class test,

while i am trying to run the test using Maven project.

Comment: Can you show us your work please?

Comment: With that little information do you really hope someone can help you? And how does [tag:selenium] relate?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First check You have java installed in your system by command prompt by typing javac.
If its installed then you need to add your class path in your IDE if you are using Eclipse then Preferences>>Java>>Installed JREs>> then edit location to your jdk.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the version of your Eclipse TestNG Plugin ? and whats the version of TestNG dependency you added in your project?

I have faced similar error where my TestNG Eclipse plugin was 7.9.10 but i was trying to use latest TestNG version 7.11 in pom.xml.

Make sure you give same version of TestNG dependency at that of eclipse testng plugin.

-Vikas Thange